# Predicate function to determine if two indexes have the same levels

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I need to write an predicate function to determine if two indexes have the same tuples. This is probably something which has been solved a million times.

Given the following two measure tables

```
                   wave
respondent source      
0          1          1
1          1          1
2          1          2
3          1          2
4          1          1
0          2          2
1          2          2
2          2          1
3          2          1
4          2          2


                   score
respondent source      
0          1          1
1          1          1
2          1          2
3          1          2
4          1          1


same_indexes(df_a, df_b)
```

The output would be

```
[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

it should ideally handle the indexes in different orders and would need to handle variable numbers of indexes.

Comment: I don't understand the desired algorithm. Why are there eight items in your output, when your data frames have 10 and 5 rows respectively? Also, when you say "index", do you mean the index entry for one row, which is a tuple like `(0,1)`, `(1,1)`, etc.? Note that in Pandas terminology, "index" is the collection of _all_ the index entries, and that each `DataFrame` has exactly _one_ index.

Comment: Sorry, there should have been an output per row (10 items). When I said index I did mean the index entry for one row, which is a tuple like (0,1)

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly: you want something which goes through each row of `df_a`, takes that row's index entry, and tells you whether there is a row in `df_b` with the same index entry?

Comment: yip that is exactly it

Comment: OK. You might consider editing your question to clarify that, so it will still be clear after these comments disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pandas `Index` (or `MultiIndex`, as in your question) implements the [`isin` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) which will do exactly what you're looking for. Use it as `df_a.index.isin(df_b.index)`.

Comment: hmm this looks pretty close to what I need but the result is not what I would expect `object_to_filter.index.isin(filter_index)
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)`

Comment: Is this the output you get for the example in your question? If so, that's not what I get. Granted, I'm using Python 3, but the results should be the same; I can't think of any differences between Python 3 and 2.7 that would account for this.